# regex to exclude string unless another string exists

Tags: regex, fluentd

I'm currently working on a fluentd regex expression to match all log entries unless the message contains the string "dbug". However, if the log contains both "dbug" and "firing" in the entry then I need the regex to match that string.

The two strings can appear anywhere in the log entry however "dbug" will always be before "firing".

Is it possible to build a single regex expression that can do this?

I'd appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using lookaheads here, e.g.

```
^(?:(?!.*\bdbug\b)|(?=.*\bdbug\b.*\bfiring\b)).*$
```

### Demo

The first lookahead `(?!.*\bdbug\b)` matches any line which does not contain `dbug` at all, and the second lookahead `(?=.*\bdbug\b.*\bfiring\b)` matches any line which contains both `dbug` and `firing`, in that order.